# Circular progress indicator with animation at end

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, effect

I need to create a modal alert with some animated progress indicator. I've found this example below, and I'd like to create something like this:

[image]

I already know how to implement the circular progress indicator, but this effect at the end is new to me.

Has anyone seen a similar effect? (Circular progress indicator with effect in the end)

Is this some kind of gif? And if it is, how can I add a gif to a view on Android?

Comment: Check out Lottie from Airbnb

Comment: Alex Lockwood has an example that is quite similar here: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this well known library [AnimCheckBox](https://github.com/lguipeng/AnimCheckBox). Here is an screenshot what will you get.

[image]

## How to use?

Add this dependency to your app level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.hanks.animatecheckbox:library:0.1'
}
```

Then in your `layout.xml`

```
<com.hanks.library.AnimateCheckBox
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    app:animDuration="200"
    app:checkedColor="#00f"
    app:lineColor="#fff"
    app:lineWidth="1.2dp"
    app:unCheckColor="#ff0"/>
```

Comment: Why did people downvote above question instead of telling him way?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Khemraj!